# How to print multiple row with several columns in a template?

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli, foreach

I have a problem to find a way to get the MySQL-Result returned into an array which contains the data from the statement for every row and column.

controller.class.php:

```
class Controller {

  private $template;
  private $view;
  private $data;

  public function __construct() {
    $this->view = new View();
    $this->data = new Model();
  }

  public function display() {
      $this->view->setTemplate();
      $this->view->setContent("title", "Songs");
      $this->view->setContent("content", $this->data->getAllDataFromSongs());
      $this->view->setContent("footer", "&copy My name is Jeff\n");

      return $this->view->parseTemplate();
  }

}
```

model.class.php:

```
class Model {
  public $db_connection = null;

  public function __construct() {
    $this->openDatabaseConnection();
  }

  private function openDatabaseConnection() {     
    $this->db_connection = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

    if ($this->db_connection->connect_error) {
      die('Connect Error (' . $this->db_connection->connect_errno . ') '
        . $this->db_connection->connect_error);
    }
  }

  public function getAllDataFromSongs() {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM songs";
    $row_content = array();

    if ($result = $this->db_connection->query($query)){

        while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
          array_push($row_content, $row['id']);
          array_push($row_content, $row['artist']);
          array_push($row_content, $row['song']);
          array_push($row_content, $row['year']);
        }

        $result->free();

      return $row_content;
    }
    else
      echo 'No results';
  }

}
```

view.class.php:

```
class View {

  private $path         = 'templates';
  private $template;
  private $content  = array();

  public function setContent($key, $value){
    $this->content[$key] = $value;
  }

  public function setTemplate($template = 'default') {
    $this->template = $this->path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $template . '.tpl.php';
  }

  public function parseTemplate() {
    if (file_exists($this->template)) {

            ob_start();
            require_once('templates/header.tpl.php');
            include_once $this->template;
            require_once('templates/footer.tpl.php');
            $output = ob_get_contents();
            ob_end_clean();

      return $output;
    }
    else{
      return "Can't find ".$this->template." Template";
    }
  }
}
```

default.tpl.php:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>artist</th>
    <th>song</th>
    <th>year</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <?php 
    foreach ($this->content['content'] as $con){
        echo '<td>'.  $con . '</td>';
    }
    ?>
  </tr>
</table>

<br>
<?php echo $this->content['footer']; ?>
```

It's not the entire Code, but it should show you what I'm trying.
The problem which I have now, is that the result from getAllDataFromSongs() is an Array with all Datas in behind each other. I can't separate them in a table.

This is the output:

```
Array ( 
  [0] => 1 [1] => Artist 1 [2] => Song 1 [3] => Year 1
  [4] => 2 [5] => Artist 2 [6] => Song 2 [7] => Year 2
  [8] => 3 [9] => Artist 3 [10] => Song 3 [11] => Year 3 
  [12] => 4 [13] => Artist 4 [14] => Song 4 [15] => Year 4
  [16] => 5 [17] => Artist 5[18] => Song 5 [19] => Year 5 
)

ID artist song year 
1 Artist 1Song 1Year 12Artist 2Song 2Year 2 3Artist 3Song 3Year 3...
```

I hope you can relate what I'm trying to explain..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
      array_push($row_content, $row['id']);
      array_push($row_content, $row['artist']);
      array_push($row_content, $row['song']);
      array_push($row_content, $row['year']);
    }
```

Your problem here is that you are creating a new array element for each column, so in the end you will have them all one after the other, one the same level.

Either create a temporary array first, and then assign that (so that you get rows of columns),

```
    while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
      $temp = [];
      array_push($temp, $row['id']);
      array_push($temp, $row['artist']);
      array_push($temp, $row['song']);
      array_push($temp, $row['year']);

      array_push($row_content, $temp);
    }
```

Or, assign just the full row array directly:

```
    while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
      array_push($row_content, $row);
      // $row_content[] = $row; // same thing
    }
```

If you get additional columns from your SELECT statement that you don’t want in here, then you should name the columns directly in the SELECT statement, instead of selecting `*`.)

Additionally, [`mysqli_result::fetch_all`](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) also exists. That function puts *all* rows in the result set in an array in one go - so you could do away with the `while` loop completely.

Comment: I've tryed the first solution and I'm getting now an array with arrays for each row inside... how can I fetch the table in my default.tpl.php file?

Comment: @Alex add a nested foreach to a template?